# Could I submit app to appstore without ios device?

Tags: iphone, app-store, simulator

Today I want submit my app to app store, I created apple ID and prepared app for upload. I created Distribution Provisioning Profile and I prepared everything in xcode but when I change
iPhone Simulator 6.1 -> iOS Device (button archive is unavaible)

Check dependencies

> Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the
>   application's Identifier 'com.etomek.Ukladanka' could not be found

I thought that I need Developer Provisioning Profile? But I don't have any iPhone/iPad

So Could I submit app to appstore without ios device ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a device, and can archive when it's set to iOS Device. The best bet is to test on as many devices as you can, and archive when it's plugged in. Although when it says iOS Device, you can archive. The reason it's grayed out is probably an error in your provisioning profile or certificate. You may want to look under Organizer under profiles or under your build settings.

You need a development certificate for testing locally and distribution certificate for submission to the app store. You need to create a request in keychain then submit it using iTunes Connect, and then download the proper provisioning profiles and certs, and install it in XCode Organizer.

Best bet is to purchase a cheap device like an iPod Touch or iPhone, that can test most of your capabilities (iPod doesn't have most capabilities). You can compile for iPad with iPod or iPhone. So you just need an iOS device that can support your version 4.3+ or 5,6,7.

My previous answer was not correct, but this one is. Trausti was actually correct.

Comment: This is just plain and simple wrong answer. You don't need any device except for a mac and Xcode to deliver app to App Store

Comment: I cannot archive. I get this error after selecting archive: "Unable to create a provisioning profile because your team has no devices registered in the Member Center. Please connect a device, enable it for development, and add it to the Member Center using the Organizer."

Comment: What version of XCode are you using? It's slightly different for 6.x+

Answer (score 1):

From [Official Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html)

> **To create an archive**
>
> 1. For iOS, tvOS, and watchOS apps, choose a generic device or your device name from the Scheme toolbar menu in the project editor.
>
>    You can’t create an archive of a simulator build. If a device is connected to your Mac, the device name appears in the Scheme toolbar menu. When you disconnect the device, the menu item changes to the generic device.
> 2. Choose Product > Archive.
>
>    The Archives organizer appears and displays the new archive.

So you don't need an iOS Device to create an archive and distribute it on the App Store or for beta/ad-hoc testing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can submit your app to app store without having a device.

The error you have is most likely because of incorrect name of your application.

Comment: I've released several apps with a completely "virgin" developer account without ever registering a device.. i've tested using other accounts though. but for only distributing it, one does not need a device. (it's just hard to set up correct profiles, certificates, code signing if you're new to the system)

Comment: so how you grayed out archive options ?

Comment: You are right, you can archive when it says iOS Device. Just never had. I tried to upvote but it won't let me. Anyhow, kudos, pretty fundamental thing that we overlooked (the ones who said you can not). I've just never done it like that.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. Also if you are wanting to do a clean distribution you will need to get a distribution license so you can do the distribution directly from xcode. Here is a good tutorial.
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview/publishing_to_the_app_store

Comment: Absoutely right. Disto License from ITunes Connect. YOu need to submit your cert request from your keychain. There are a bunch of tutorials on Google.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a device in order to submit:

1. You cannot archive the app if xcode is set to simulator
2. You do not have to run the app on the device, but you must connect
   it in order to archive it. That is why the menu is not
   avalaible(grayed out)
3. PS: Also , you do not want to submit an app wihtout testing it on a real
   device, that's just my opinion though.

Comment: +1 on bullet point 3. You need to be able to test out gestures. Swipes, multi touch, long taps, etc. You can only do so much with simulators ;)

Comment: No, you don't need a device. In xcode, you just pick iOS Device instead of a simulator, even though there is no device connected. Go to Project and pick archive. In the wizard there is an option to send to App Store