# Xcode 8 asks for a device to be registered to create provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to publish an app for testing, without having to connect a device in my mac.

I have created a developer account, created an app in itunes, generated bundle id, signed into xcode with the developer account, generated a distributor certificate.

When I tried to archive the app, I got the error "conflict provisioning setting. app is automatically signed for development ..."

I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824727/i-get-conflicting-provisioning-settings-error-when-i-try-to-archive-to-submit-an) and followed the tip of unchecking and rechecking the option "Automatically manage signing". After re-choosing my team, I get the error "There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it".

The goal all along was that I wouldn't need an ios device, because I intended to immediately publish the application and invite people to test it via testflight. Is it not possible to do it like this? Am I missing something.

I have read lots of documentation, but being a first timer in this, everything seems confusing.

Edit: I created a provisioning profile as distributor. Even after creating and installing the distributor profile (it now appears also in xcode at Account -> provisioning profiles), I still get that same error. I also noticed that in signing, The signing certificate is iOS Developer.  I am sure

[image]

Comment: Please do check the provisioning profile for distribution in your developer account.

Comment: In case you don't get the process, then you can refer to this link http://codewithchris.com/submit-your-app-to-the-app-store/

Comment: @PIYUSHMATHUR Ok, i noticed that I had created a distribution certificate, but not a provisioning profile.

Comment: Then go through this video for reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnbOcpwJGa8

Comment: hey Freya did you find any answer to this??

Comment: @UmaAchanta The solution I found is posted below. But I am not a very reliable apple user, so I think I will let other people give a better or more explained solution before accepting my answer.

Comment: I know it is a kind of off-topic. But to print screen an area on a Mac: Command + Control + Shift + 4. It goes to your clipboard. Sick hotkey.

Comment: @VitorHugoSchwaab: Thanks. I am not really a Mac user and hope to never again have to work with one, but if I do, your advice will really come in  handy.

Comment: Same here. Been in another iOS project for the last month. My biggest motivation to finish it is to stop using the Mac.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The solution (though I would welcome more elaborate, insightful explanations):

- @General -> Signing, disable the option "Automatically manage signing"
- @General -> Signing and certificates choose your team

Though in my case that was not the issue, I would recommend making sure that in the device list, you choose Generic iOS device in your target devices.

Comment: Manual management of the app signing feature is actually more accurate as it makes the connection to the provisioning profile and certificate more clear.

Comment: Always archive an app for upload using "Generic" which will not be device specific.

Comment: If I uncheck 'automatically manage signing', it doesn't let me select a team - team is stuck on 'None'.

Comment: @Ali, did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 47):

I fixed it by plugging in my iPhone and going to the **`Product`** menu > **`Destination`** > **`iPhone`** (my device).

Then after clicking <kbd>Try Again</kbd> on this properties page the warnings went away.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46820806/1678614)

Comment: Thank you! you saved my day

Comment: Worked for me as well, thanks!

Comment: this is the answer. Many thanx

Answer (score 5):

This really sucked to figure out.

What you do is add a distribution profile in https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/add.  Don't choose development!  Don't let the Xcode Automatically manage signing!!

Then, you download the provision.

Then, in the Signing & Capabilities -> Signing Section of the project.xcodeproj file, turn off Automatcially manage signing, choose import and import the file you just downloaded.

Then, in the top, you choose Any iOS Device (arm64, armv7) and then you go Product -> Archive.

[image: image of it]

Comment: On the import step, it won't let me import the certificate file type?

Comment: what's the error you are getting ?  did you download the provision file ?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i worked it out (cant remember how though).

Answer (score 2):

If you do not wish to register a device follow this advice:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44157307/499581

```
* In short use "Generic" as the device while archiving.
```

If you do wish to register a device then the solution to:

> "There are no devices registered in your account on the developer
>   website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it".

Is to physically plug-in your device (an actual iPhone, or iPad) so that Xcode can register it for development use (note: this will not affect the normal everyday use of the device). After the device is registered it can then be used for development testing, load provisioning profiles onto it, etc.

↳ [Disabling and Enabling Devices Using Your Developer Account](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev45162157e)

Answer (score 2):

What happened to me was that I was about to run my app on a physical device for the first time and I didn't have a Team. So I created it in the process before connecting my phone with the USB cable. After I created the team a message like the listed above appeared. I did some research on internet but nothing found.

So here's what I did: I connected my phone, did all the trusted process, then restarted Xcode, and it worked. I am not sure what happened, but it was some of my first experiences using Xcode. It could sounds silly but it helped me. Hope to you too.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are trying to develop without a mac computer using *MacInCloud* don't follow the standard advice out there. Its will lead you down a hole. I have wasted hours of my time.

The reason it say something about **"a device to be registered to create provisioning profile"** is that you need to provision an iOS device that you can test on before you can get it signed. If you are using *MacInCloud* you probably can't physically connect an iPhone or iPad to the *MacInCloud* and therefore it can't automatically provision devices for you.

Before you get to far into this you will need to get your iPhone/iPad UDID. Which I was able to do with https://get.udid.io/ on my iPhone, but it didn't work on my iPad. Instead, with the iPad I had to download iTunes from the Windows store and connect my iPad. Then click on the little gray square in the menu that's inline with Library tab.
[image of itunes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZufY.png)

Then when it pops up with your device info (mine didn't come up with my info at first, I had to sync my device). You will see your SN. Click on your SN and it will change to your UDID. Once you have your UDID you are ready to create a provisioning profile. What is confusing is this isn't done in the appstoreconnect section of your account online. Its done in your developer account: https://developer.apple.com/account
[developer.apple.com account screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m8EV.png)
When you go there you will want to click: Certificates, Ids & Profiles

Here you will need to add your devices and then with auto signing checked in Xcode that made the problem go away. *NOTE: I originally tried to create a profile, download it, and import into Xcode under the Provisioning Profile dropdown in Signing & Capabilities. As described in another answer here, but that proved more problematic and wasn't necessary.*

Then you can chose Any iOS Device from emulator device drop down then go to Product > Archive > Distribute App and create a certificate to place it on the app store (TestFlight).

Answer (score -1):

you can also plug an iphone, run the app the app on your iphone as the target, it will ask you to register the device and then the certificates will be generated

Answer (score -8):

Have you paid the $99/year developer fee? TestFlight is only available for paid developers. I would highly recommend plugging in an iOS device, though. It's more fun and rewarding testing that way.

Comment: Yes i have. The account I used is the developer account for which I paid the fee. Plugging a device is not an option, since I do not have an ios device, hence the plan to publish the application in testflight.