# Uploading iOS app to Appstore: Code Signing Error

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to submit the app for review on App Store. However, I **don't have an iPhone**. I've tested the app in Xcode v9.2 simulator and it works fine. Now, I can't seem to be able to submit it. I'm using Ionic Framework to build the app, and it's already working on Google Play.

I've created all certificates in my developer account, ticked the automatic signing box and selected General iOS device. Next step is to `product -> archive` which spits out the following error.

```
Code Signing Error: Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.
Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'com.example' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.example'.
```

Do I really need an iPhone to push this app for review? I also tried `product -> build for -> all options`

Comment: Hey, try this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18724696/2776008

Comment: @QuocNguyen Thanks, but these are exactly the steps I described when it fails. I also selected the general iOS device, and when I archive, it fails. The question you linked solves `archive` button greyed out.